# Does Azure Storage Queue, not have an event for New Message Arrival?

Tags: c#, azure

Have been looking out for analogous to Azure service bus queue, where messaging pump use to fire OnMessage(BrokeredMessage msg) whenever a new message arrives.

> Does Azure Storage Queue, not have such event supported?

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Get the next message
CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = queue.GetMessage();

//Process the message in less than 30 seconds, and then delete the message
queue.DeleteMessage(retrievedMessage);
```

Answer (score 3):

Natively this feature is not supported with Azure Storage Queues. A client need to poll a queue to check for new messages in that queue.

You could simulate the event based behavior by using Functions or WebJobs Triggers. However internally they will be polling the queue and invoke the function/webjob (or in other words raise an event), whenever they find a message in a queue.